# Is there a way to inform already existing users of iOS app about version updates?

Tags: ios, updates

Is there a way to update already existing users of an iOS app about version updates? Let's say my current production version is 1.3 and I have users in 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 that are already using the app? How do I send a message to users using the older versions about the latest version? Frameworks like [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) and [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion) help you do that but only for version updates after the version in which these tools are integrated, i.e. if I put one of these in version 1.4 of my app, I can inform users from 1.4 onwards, but what about users who are stuck in 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3?

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Actually you can't do anything if there is nothing that handles it on the already released applications. If you have the user email you can try to send an email, that's the only solution I got

Comment: If you have Push notifications enabled, then you can send a message to all of the users. However, even new users will recive the message.

Comment: You can add custom API to check latest version of the application on the launch of the app. If version is different then can show the alert to update the version of the app.

Comment: use iVersion library.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic updating is not possible, the user should download the latest version of the app by him/her self. What you can do is adding a feature to your app that forces the user to update -and maybe optional update- to your application, for example:

Let's say you want to force 1.1 users to update and suggest 1.2 users to update to the latest version, you need to check the current used version:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
```

If it's 1.1, you might want to display a scene that contains a message and a button (the only option that user has is tapping the button for updating). If it's 1.2, you might want to display a scene that contains a message and two buttons, one for updating and the other is "no, thanks".

And of course you can check verions as ranges, for example:

current version is 2.0:

[1.0 - 1.5] -> force updating.

[1.6 - 1.9] -> optional updating.

Hope that helped.

Comment: That doesn't address PO's concern. He wants to force an update for previous, already shipped versions (without modifying them) - and that is impossible.

Comment: "Automatic updating is not possible, the user should download the the latest version of the app by him/her self." :)

Comment: For future versions, he should checks the app version to prevent facing this issue...